# Getting one item's value from an array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I searched for this but all i found is .each() api and I couldn't find a way to get what I want.  This is what my array looks like:

```
Customer : Array
(
   [name]=>Andrew
   [age]=>23
   .......
   [address]=>london
   .......
)

CustomerDet: Array
(
   [other]=>done
   [misc]=>todo
)
```

How can I get the value of, say, address?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please tell me those are not "associative arrays"

Comment: `alert(Customer['address'])`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(Customer, function(index, value) { 
  alert(value.address); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use each to do something like this, which would populate the `userAddress` variable with the address for the first user it finds with the name'Andrew' -

```
var userAddress;
jQuery.each(CustomerArray,function(index, value) {
   if (value.name == "Andrew") {
     userAddress = value.address;
     return false;  
  }
})
```